# How strong was the Genki Dama Goku made to defeat Jiren?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

Goku tried to defeat Jiren with a Super Saiyan Blue Kaioken x20 and he failed. Then he decided to use his best technique, the Genki Dama to defeat him. One would think the Genki Dama had to be stronger than the Super Saiyan Blue kaioken x20, but in other hand, where did he get the energy from? They were surrounded by void, and the only powerfull warriors we see giving power to Goku are Freezer,17,Gohan and in a lesser level Piccolo and 18 (Krilin, Tien and Roshi contribution would be minimal).

How strong was the Genki Dama Goku made to defeat Jiren?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, we can't really gauge how strong it is because we don't exactly know how much energy these fighters contribute to the spirit bomb. In the sense, none of the fighters were tired or out of energy after contributing to the Spirit Bomb. Plus, it was essentially missing the energy of Universe 7's 2 strongest fighters "Goku and Vegeta".

Logically, it doesn't make sense for the Spirit Bomb to be stronger than Super Saiyan Blue Kaioken Goku as the Spirit Bomb would have to be at a Universal Level if that were the case and the only fighter who contributed sufficient energy to be categorized at a universal level, would be Frieza(Yet, he was in his final form which isn't universal). If you were to consider the SSJG Goku from the Battle of Gods arc at a universal level, you could essentially consider Gohan at his full power to be around that level however, even he wasn't in his Ultimate form when he contributed energy.

So essentially, I believe the theme of the attack was more or less on the lines of, *"Since I cannot defeat you myself, this is a combined attack from the whole of Universe 7"*.

For the sake of plot, they made the attack look extremely powerful as even the Gods of Destruction of every universe was astonished with this level of power.

Although I personally disagree with this line and feel it logically doesn't make sense, as far as the show goes, **Whis makes a statement that Kefla's might as a Super Saiyan, rivalled the spirit bomb**. **Kefla as a Super Saiyan was around the same level as Super Saiyan Blue Goku**. **Hence, based on that, the spirit bomb should be around that level of power.**

Comment: lol, I was about to make another question about that line. That would prove Kefla is stronger than Vegeta Super Saiyan Blue Evolution and Toppo. I think not only the Genki Dama proves that, but also the fact that she was able to knock Goku Super Saiyan Blue Kaioken, when she wasnt even in her super saiyan 2 form

Comment: BTW, she was about the same level than super saiyan blue kaioken, which is quite more powerful than super saiyan blue alone. Perhaps Goku got stronger after being re-energyzed by Freezer, kinda like a senkai boost. So the Goku super saiyan blue kaiokenx20 against Kefla would be stronger than the one he used against Jiren

Comment: @Pablo Actually, Kefla isn't stronger than Super Saiyan Blue Kaioken. Champa constantly repeats the fact that Goku was very exhausted and Kaioken strains the body severely. Goku's was just too tired to put up a fight and eventually fainted because of the surprise kick. An exhausted SSJB Goku was very relative to SSJ Kefla.

Comment: @Pablo I wouldn't say Kefla is stronger than SSJB+ Kaioken * 20 Goku or SSBE Vegeta and G.O.D Toppo. If her SSJ was relative to an exhausted SSJB Goku/ SSJ2 is 2 times SSJ and even if you factor in the rage boost etc, she'd have to be several times > than the SSJ3 multiplier to even remotely come close to SSJB+KK*20 Goku and SSBE Vegeta and G.O.D Toppo compare to this level of power. I think most people tend to overlook the fact that Goku was completely drained out before this fight which is one of the reason Kefla had the upperhand.